# How to change git repo's owner?

Tags: git

I used the `root` user to `init`, `add`, and `commit` git repo. (bad habit)
Now, I create a new normal user `me`.
How to let `me` to handle the repo made by `root`?

Comment: Except when you need to change the system's configuration or start/stop services, stay away from the `root` user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

`sudo chown` ***user[:group]*** `. -R`

from within the repositories folder to change the owner, where ***user*** is the desired user (and optionally a ***group*** name may also be supplied).

Comment: Is it means, `root` can handle any user's git repo with the same config?

Comment: I think that depends on your configuration structure. If you have settings withing your user's directory, they will differ from the ones used for root. But access-wise, root should be able to read repos or at least to gain access to them.